# Появление результата по нажатию кнопки

Tags: javascript

Доброго всем времени. Столкнулся с такой проблемой.
Сделал калькулятор. При выборе/расчете, сумма показывается внизу в процессе расчетов. Нужно, чтобы сумма появилась не сразу а при нажатии кнопки "Рассчитать".

Вот как  оно выглядит в теле сайта:

```html
<div class="calc-result">
  <span class="str" data-edit="" contenteditable="true">Итого сумма заказа: <span class="green"><span id="CalculatorResult">0</span> руб.</span>
  </span>
  <button class="button-yellow"><span>Рассчитать</span>
  </button>
  <button class="button-yellow" data-modal="Modal-order"><span>Заказать</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

Как видите, строка приведенная ниже выводит получаемую сумму:

```html
<span class="str" data-edit="" contenteditable="true">Итого сумма заказа: <span class="green"><span id="CalculatorResult">0</span> руб.</span>
```

Помогите разобраться.

Comment: Надо код скрипта смотреть

Comment: убери `0` из `<span id="CalculatorResult">0</span>` и не будет выводить

Comment: Если "0" убрать - выводить будет. При нажатии на любой из перечней.

Comment: Скрипт могу скинуть, но думаю эта портянка тут не поможет. Как я понимаю, нужно спрятать строку отображения суммы до нажатия на кнопку "расчет".

Comment: Если нужно чтобы оно не рассчитывалось до нажатии на кнопку, то надо спрятать элемент по-умолчанию. Привязать событие на кнопку "рассчитать":

1) производим рассчет
2) показываем кнопку

Comment: @Pleshevskiy да может и рассчитываться. главное чтоб не показывалось. А вот кнопка "Заказать", желательно чтоб появлялась после нажатия кнопки "Рассчитать".
Уф... Что-то я вообще запарился. мозг лопнит. Попробовал html-ом реализовать. Бред получается...

Answer (score 1):

Задачу решил. Если кому в перспективе потребуется:

```html
<div class="calc-result">

  <span class="str" data-edit="" contenteditable="true" style="display: none;" id="pr">Итого сумма заказа: <span class="green"><span id="CalculatorResult">0</span> руб.</span>
  <button class="button-yellow" data-modal="Modal-order"><span>Заказать</span>
  </button>
  </span>
  <button class="button-yellow" onclick="document.getElementById('pr').style.display='block'; return false;"><span>Рассчитать</span>
  </button>

</div>
```

Работает. Осталось только выровнять кнопку "расчета". Уползла вниз.